# MYSQL Sorting Data into a Pattern

Tags: mysql, sorting

Not sure if this is possible...

Given this data in MYSQL:

```
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
AAA
CCC
DDD
DDD
```

How could I return a result set sorted in a pattern like this:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, you're likely heading into a world of pain.

Comment: I think this problem/question is way under-defined as of now. Will there always be the same number of records for all four “categories”? If not, what is the desired result after you run out of, say, `CCC` records, but there’s still plenty of the others? Assuming those records contain not only this column, but more and with different values even with a “category” - do you need those in a specific order, or does it not matter which of the records matching `CCC` comes first?

Comment: I have a real-world problem including a table with a primary index. I may have oversimplified my question. However, the accepted answer was perfect for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT mycol
FROM (
   SELECT mycol,
          @rnk := IF(@col = mycol, @rnk + 1,
                     IF(@col := mycol, 1, 1)) AS grp
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @col := '') AS vars
   ORDER BY mycol) AS t
ORDER BY grp, mycol;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/YQSFX37772)